# How can I set the jenkins authentication token?

Tags: jenkins

On my Jenkins build server, I want to set an Authentication Token so that only users that know the token can fire off builds.  (As described [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API).)

[This doc page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Quick+and+Simple+Security) says that it should be configurable under my job's "Build Triggers" configuration.

However, my server has no such fields, and I'm running the latest version (1.546).  Mine looks like this:

[image: this].

As you can see, this doesn't really look like the docs say it should.

How can I set this token?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're missing the **Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)** Build Trigger:

[image: Trigger builds remotely]

This is only visible with Security enabled.  To get this option from a freshly downloaded 1.546 WAR, I changed **Configure Global Security** from **Anyone can do anything** to at least **Logged-in users can do anything**.  For ease/speed of testing, under **Security Realm** I selected **Jenkins’ own user database** and **Allow users to sign up**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can go to **http://Jenkins-IP/jobs/me/configure** to check and change your API access token. Also check whether the user you intend to use has necessary permissions to execute the builds in Manage Jenkins>Configure Global Security

Answer (score 0):

Each jenkins user gets an authentication token - applicable since version 1.426 ([more](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/api-token-jenkins-rest-api)).

You can see yours, provided you are logged in your jenkins server, at http://your.jenkins.server/me/configure
(press 'show API token' button)

Then you can copy and paste it in your scripts (e.g. see [here](https://gist.github.com/glombard/3f41a5d7b1c0cadffb5f#file-jenkins-backup-job-config-py-L9) for an example usage).

Comment: Any way to get one for anonymous user?

Comment: Not that I know of. Maybe a solution would be setting up an actual user named 'anonymous' with the rights you want her to have and work with her token.