# Trigger a Openshift Jenkins Job via command line (CURL)

Tags: curl, openshift, redhat, kubernetes-helm, jenkins-api

I am trying to trigger a job present in jenkins hosted in openshift platform. I am trying to trigger the job through command line.

I tried the below:

curl -x post -u username:password https://myjenkins.com/job/myjob/build?delay=0sec

and this resulted in

Invalid password/token for user:

1. I tried to use create a token in jenkins and supplied that too and no luck.
2. I removed the user id and password from my curl command and that resulted in the error message No valid crumb was included in the request
3. I then tried to do a wget to get a crumb. The command runs but does not return anything

./wget -q --auth-no-challenge --user username --password password --output-document - 'https://myjenkins/crumbIssuer/api/json'

4. 'Options Enable proxy compatibility' and the 'Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits' are checked in jenkins security configuration

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To trigger builds remotely, you need to create an authentication token too.

- [How can I set the jenkins authentication token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032349/how-can-i-set-the-jenkins-authentication-token)

Once you have the authentication token, you can pass it as a parameter while making the request like `job/myjob/build?token=<authentication-token>`.

You can perform the operation using either `username:password` or `username:apiToken`.

```sh
$ curl -x post -u username:password http://myjenkins.com/job/myjob/build?token=wefiytgw...
$ curl -x post -u username:apiToken http://myjenkins.com/job/myjob/build?token=wefiytgw...
```

You can also take a look to this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/888248).